# Any Sledgehammer Tire target alternatives - Ballistic/Extremely High Density rubber OR Plyometric Foam? [Not exercise alternatives Pls]

Tags: gym, core, conditioning, functional-strength

Hi Can someone provide alternative to a tire for sledgehammer swing? I currently have a sledge hammer but cannot accommodate a tire in my home.

I am thinking of using this - Can anyone comment?

https://www.titan.fitness/3-in-1-soft-foam-plyometric-box-20-24-30.html?

https://www.range-systems.com/shop/

https://www.clearballistics.com/shop/20-ballistic-gelatin-ballistics-air-block/

http://www.blackironrubber.com/

http://cumberlandrubber.com/blocks.html

Comment: If you type *sledgehammer exercises without tire* into Google, you'll get a plethora of options. And no, using an item meant for box jumps to instead slam a sledgehammer into is probably not recommended.

Comment: I just need a tire alternative buddy. Also can you comment if the soft foam will work.

Comment: Newer content for question added. They are talking about exercise alternatives as well. I am not open for same.

Comment: @SeanDuggan could you pls remove "Q already answered here if possible". Thanks

Comment: I can delete my comment, but the link will remain, as will the close vote. I revised my answer to fit your question. Is there more I can give you?

Answer (score 0):

Options people have listed as alternatives as seen in [this thread on tire alternatives](http://forums.sherdog.com/threads/sledgehammer-workout-without-tire.1181343/):

- Rolled up snow fence
- Rolled up rug / carpet
- Old gym or horse stall mats
- Piles of carpet tiles
- Anything soft that you don't mind destroying
- Mats over a medicine ball (recreates some of the bounce)
- [Shovelgloving](http://www.shovelglove.com/) - Eliminates the striking part in favor of using the sledgehammer as a weight.

I do not think that the foam block you suggested is likely to be a good choice namely because the recurring theme in targets suggested is that it be something that you don't mind getting damaged over time because the edges of the sledgehammer will eventually start to gouge holes in most materials. That said, although Rogue Fitness does not endorse such usage, some people use [their block](https://www.roguefitness.com/rogue-ballistic-block) for sledgehammer workouts. If you look at the reviews, most people using it for that purpose approve of it, but one of them suggests only using it with a round-headed mace-style hammer and another states the first sledgehammer hit gouged out a three inch chunk of the rubber.

That said, there are also people who swear by those blocks. As regards the other ones you've posted, I have no personal experience with any brand, but you're going to be looking for something made out of hard rubber, giving enough to that it does not shatter or damage the hammer, but firm enough that it does not tear. Ballistics gel is not what you want; it's built for things like analyzing the effects of bullets or edged weapons on human flesh, and will tear. Most of the other products you have listed are ballistics rubber, the sort of material that you put at the back of a shooting range to stop bullets.

Ultimately, I cannot find any product which advertises its use in sledgehammer workouts, and several of them specifically state that their product is not built for it. On the other hand, I've seen a number of reviews where people used them for a Sledgehammer workout and were satisfied with them. My impression is that they may be completely adequate for the purpose, and will serve as a reasonable replacement for a tire that's more portable, and a bit more palatable to have sitting at the side of the room when you have visitors. That said, they also tend to cost about $100 and because the companies do not endorse the product's use in that way, you're probably not going to be covered by the warranty should a block tear or break.

Comment: How about this http://cumberlandrubber.com/blocks.html or https://www.sorinex.com/product/sorinex-rubber-utility-block/. Basically ballistic blocks

Comment: Hi Any suggestion for sandbags that can be used?

Comment: @HiXDmf: I'm afraid not. I have no personal experience with this and I haven't found anyone espousing a sand-bag. My impulse is that, without some very tough material, you'd have issues with the sledgehammer ripping into it.